Infinite scroll displaying duplicate data before loading subsequent pages
I'm implementing an infinite scroll feature in my web application where data is fetched and displayed in cards. However, I'm encountering an issue where the initial data (1-9) is being duplicated on the UI before subsequent pages are loaded.
Here's the sequence of events:

Upon loading the page, the initial set of data (1-9) is fetched and displayed correctly.
On the initial load, I'm observing that the data set (1-9) is displayed twice, before subsequent pages are loaded upon scrolling.
Only after scrolling past the duplicate set, the data for subsequent pages (10 onwards) is fetched and displayed correctly.

Here is the code for my Home component:
`import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import MovieComponent from './MovieComponent';
import Loading from './Loading';
const Home = () => {
    const [card, setCard] = useState([]);
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    const getCardData = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(
            `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=9&_page=${page}`
        );
        const data = await res.json();
        console.log("data got is ", data);
        setCard((prev) => [...prev, ...data]);
        setLoading(false);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getCardData();
    }, [page]);

    const handleInfiniteScroll = () => {
        try {
            if (
                document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight + 1 >=
                document.documentElement.scrollHeight
            ) {
                setLoading(true);
                setPage((prev) => prev + 1);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleInfiniteScroll);
        return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleInfiniteScroll);
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <MovieComponent movieInfo={card} />
            {loading && <Loading />}
        </>
    );
};

export default Home;

`
I'm using React for my front-end and fetching data asynchronously. Could this issue be related to how I'm handling the asynchronous nature of data fetching and rendering? Or is there something else I should be looking into?
Any insights or suggestions on how to prevent the duplicate display of initial data before loading subsequent pages would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I attempted to address this by adding debouncing to the scroll event listener, hypothesizing that multiple event listeners might be triggering the duplicate display. However, despite implementing debouncing, the issue persists.

I don't think setCard works in this way.
Try replacing this with:
setCard([...card,...data])

Because the spread (...) operator creates a new array instance you should not get any issues with state race conditions.
